# TypeORM - table inheritance using enum discriminator

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

Trying to use an enum to discriminate the  child entities:

```js
export enum ActionCategory {
  USER = 'user',
  POSITION = 'position',
  NOTE = 'note',
  EMAIL = 'email',
}

@Index('action_pkey', ['id'], { unique: true })
@Entity()
@TableInheritance({
  column: { type: 'enum', enum: ActionCategory, name: 'category' },
})
export class Action {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({
    name: 'action_id',
    type: 'bigint',
  })
  readonly id: number

  @Column({
    name: 'category',
    type: 'enum',
    enum: ActionCategory,
    default: ActionCategory.USER
  })
  readonly category: ActionCategory
}
```

but I am running into an error:

```
[Nest] 52222   - 27/01/2021, 10:30:25   [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (2)... +1ms
QueryFailedError: column "action_category" contains null values
    at new QueryFailedError (/Users/rai/dev/lexstep/lexstep-nest/node_modules/.pnpm/typeorm@0.2.29/node_modules/typeorm/error/QueryFailedError.js:11:28)
I can avoid this issue by changing the name of one of the columns (either the @TableInheritance 'action_category' or the @Column 'action_category' but this results in an extra column being created
```

If I use a default value then I get the error

```
QueryFailedError: column "action_category" of relation "action" already exists
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the following way of defining entities with single inheritance:

```js
import { ChildEntity, Column, Entity, TableInheritance } from 'typeorm';
    
export enum EActionType {
    USER = 'USER',
    ADMIN = 'ADMIN',
}

// action.entity.ts
@Entity('actions')
@TableInheritance({ column: 'type' })
export abstract class ActionEntity {
    @Column({ type: 'enum', enum: EActionType, nullable: false })
    public type: EActionType;

    // ...common columns
}

// user-action.entity.ts
@ChildEntity(EActionType.USER)
export class UserActionEntity extends ActionEntity {
    public type: EActionType.USER;

    // ...user columns
}

// admin-action.entity.ts
@ChildEntity(EActionType.ADMIN)
export class AdminActionEntity extends ActionEntity {
    public type: EActionType.ADMIN;

    // ...admin columns
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to circumvent this issue by specifying the column name in the `TableInheritance` decoration:

```js
@TableInheritance({
  column: 'category',
})
```

this worked fine when leaving the `@Column` in the entity:

```js
export class Action extends Timestamped {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid', {
    name: 'action_id',
  })
  readonly id: string

  @Column({
    name: 'action_category',
    type: 'enum',
    default: ActionCategory.SYSTEM,
    enum: ActionCategory,
  })
  readonly category: ActionCategory
}
```